# heroku not registering system.properties

Tags: java, gradle, heroku, micronaut

im developing gradle micronaut app

during deployment i see
`-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8... done`
which causes errors

i've declared a system.properties file in project root folder containing single line
`java.runtime.version=17`

how do i change the java version?

Would be appreciated if somone could help me out here,

regards

I've followed numerous tutorials, most of them regard maven. I'm using gradle hence the new question